# Probe Residual vs Join Predicate

Tags: sql-server

What is the difference between a Residual and a Join predicate?

If I haven’t missed a subtlety they are exactly the same. Why confuse novices by using two different words for the same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are distinct concepts. We're right into the details of of how SQL Server plans its queries, not the place for the faint hearted! But very interesting, you won't be a "noob" for long if you're studying this area.

This [article](http://blogs.developpeur.org/raptorxp/pages/sql-server-scans-and-seeks.aspx) describes how some predicates can be interpreted to "seek", first excluding many rows, so that only a few need to be examined to determine if they match the remainder of the predicate - the residual predicate.

This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/craigfr/archive/2009/04/28/implied-predicates-and-query-hints.aspx) describes how joins are processed, and how the details of the query can lead to the decision as to whether there's a join predicate, radically affecting the performance.

Comment: Can I just say you rock for that link.

It makes sense too, I have an index ordered down date, which I'm doing a less than filter on.  So the residual was using the search order to say, from every row past this point perform the join, thus saving computation by not having to perform the date comparison for every row.

Awesome!